# os.kill() leaking "Oops: Terminated' into console

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to setup a photo frame based on a Raspberry Pi. This function is triggered by a motion sensor and loads a new image:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["pgrep", "fbi"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for pid in proc.stdout:
    os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGTERM)
subprocess.call(["fbi","-noverbose","-a","-T","1","/home/pi/photoframe/photos/"+current_image],
                 stdout=shutup,
                 stderr=shutup)
```

This works great, however every time `os.kill()` is called I get

```
Oops: Terminated
```

displayed on the screen for a brief instant before the next image appears.

Previously, I was using the -T 2 option for the fbi command. This led to an additional line:

```
map: vt02 => fb0
```

Now I only get the one "oops"-line...

Does anyone have an idea how to prevent this?
I'd be fine with a solution where the tty text is simply set to black on black - if that is even possible... I hunted for a solution but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can search and kill processes with the [`pkill`](http://man.cx/?page=pkill&do%5Bgo%5D=go) command (variant of `pgrep`).

```
os.system('pkill fbi')
```

Comment: Yes, that command also kills the process but still displays `Oops: Terminated` on my screen... That's what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to 'silence' the tty. Or redirect os.system()'s output to a log file or /dev/null instead of displaying it on screen.

Comment: try `os.system('pkill fbi >/dev/null 2>/dev/null')`

Comment: sadly, that had no effect... any other idea?

Comment: hmm: the message may be from the 'fbi' process, vs the pkill command.  Try suppressing its stderr also.  Another trick via @dede -- `subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w')`.  I wasn't able to replicate the issue on my Linux Mint (~Debian) machine. :(

Comment: The fbi command is silenced via the stdout and stderr flags in the code above. `shutup` is defined as `shutup = open("/dev/null","w")`

Comment: if I omit the `os.system('pkill fbi')` line and keep adding fbi instances, the `Oops: Terminated` message doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up using **SIGHUP** which solved it.